# Unwanted Page Redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file index.php in which there is a download button with id="render". Im using ajax to send request to server. The js code im using is:

```js
$('#render').click(function(e){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    var url='render.php';
    $.showLoading(); 
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '', 
            success: function(data){
              $.hideLoading(); 
            }
      });
  });
```

The render.php file generates a pdf document containing user data. To generate pdf im using mpdf php library. And the code of render.php file is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['template'])){
    $template=$_SESSION['template'];
    ob_start();
    require_once("resumeTemplates/$template.php");
    $template = ob_get_clean();

    require_once 'mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';

    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($template);
    $mpdf->Output("resume.pdf","D"); //sends pdf file to browser
}
?>
```

The problem is when the download button is clicked the page is redirected to render.php, but i want user to stay on index.php. I also tried to add

```
header("location:index.php");
```

but the page wasn't redirecited to index.php. It stays on render.php.

The html code for download button is:

```html
<a href="render.php" id="render" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Download</a>
```

Comment: Is it a submit button? if yes you need to use 'preventdefault();'

Comment: will you show your  html code that is button?

Comment: Thanks the problem is solved. The main problem was in html code of the button. In that I just replaced href="render.php" with href="#". Couldn't find this solution before as everything was working fine on local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `href="#"` because it will redirect before on click

```
<a href="#" id="render" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#render').click(function(e){
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    var url='render.php';
    $.showLoading(); 
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '', 
            success: function(data){
              $.hideLoading(); 
            }
      });
     e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default event when clicking button. Change your JS code like this, it should work:

```
$('#render').click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault() // this prevents page from redirect

    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1000);
    var url='render.php';
    $.showLoading(); 
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: '', 
            success: function(data){
              $.hideLoading(); 
            }
      });
  });
```